# overriding equals and hashCode - java

Tags: java

I want to override the equals and hashCode method in my Point class. I want to use the Point1 class object in my list and I want to check if on list there is a point with the same coordinates and it needn't to be the same object. only have the same values in fields.

here is my code and I have no idea why it doesn't work

```
package prac1;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

    class Point{
        private Integer x;
        private Integer y;

        Point(int x,int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = hash +(this.x != null ? this.x.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = hash/12 + (this.y != null ? this.y.hashCode() : 0); //to have unique hashCode for different objects
    return hash;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(this == other) return true; 
        if(other == null) return false; 
        if(getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

        Point1 test = (Point1)other;
        if(this.x == test.getX() && this.y == test.getY()) 
            return true; 
        return false; 
    }


       int getX(){ return this.x; }
       int getY() {return this.y; }

 }

    public class NewClass{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Point1> lista = new ArrayList<Point1>();
    Point1 t = new Point1(1,1);
    lista.add(t);

    System.out.println(lista.contains(t)); // true
    System.out.println(lista.contains(new Point1(1,1))); // false ?
}
 }
```

it returns:

```
   true
   false
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is Point1 ? is that supposed to be Point?
also: important to notice: when I run your code, assuming that Point and Point1 are supposed to be the same class, I get 'true' 'true' as result

Answer (score 3):

If I rename your `Point` class to `Point1` then it produces `true` `true` on my machine, so your code works.

There is a bug in your code however. You are using `==` on `Integer` objects. This will only work with integer values between `-128` and `127` ([reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching)) because these are cached by the JVM. But it won't work for larger/smaller values. Instead use `.equals`

```
Point1 test = (Point1)other;
if(this.x.equals(test.getX()) && this.y.equals(test.getY())) 
    return true; 
return false;
```

Here I left out an `if` for when `this.x == null` or `this.y == null` which is impossible in your code at the moment since the constructor accepts primitives only.

Comment: @user3131037 You're welcome. Can I ask why you are using integer division in your hash function? This seems like it might cause you to lose set bits and cause more hash collisions.